# Buttons in Hbox uneven width with hgrow when distributed width can't be a whole number

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have an HBox container with 3 buttons that are even in width, but when the parent's width can't be divided into whole number parts one of the nodes is less. If my HBox is 245px and I have 3 buttons 1 of them is 81px and the others are 82px.

The problem is that on top of the HBox I have a loading circle indicator and the circle is in the center of the HBox and when the middle button is not centered the loading circle also looks uncentered on top of the HBox.

```
    HBox root = new HBox();
    root.setFillHeight(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();
        HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        pane.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 245, 50, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.show();

    root.getChildren().forEach(node -> {
        AnchorPane pane = ((AnchorPane)node);
        System.out.println(pane.getWidth());
    });
```

The idea is that its a login scene and after submiting the username and password, the server is loading and there is a circle ProgressIndicator on top of the hbox and the circle is centered on top of it.

[image]

The circle looks uncentered on top of the middle button. So how can I do this with a layout container without explicity setting the width of the buttons. Do layouts always devide children on whole numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some property testing I found out that snapToPixel=false is the way to go.

From oracle docs about snapToPixel https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html

> Defines whether this region adjusts position, spacing, and size values of its children to pixel boundaries. This defaults to true, which is generally the expected behavior in order to have crisp user interfaces. A value of false will allow for fractional alignment, which may lead to "fuzzy" looking borders.

I tried different px and in my case it works fine with the edges.

Also without touching the snapToPixel I found that GridPane with 33.3% columns width palces the 81px button in the middle, where with hbox it's the last child, so GridPane also worked for me.